# GAE creating a new project?

Tags: google-app-engine

i have been working on GAE - tried to create a new project: and getting an error on command

```
abid@abid-webdev:~/Documents/GAE_projects$ python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py exe1.py/
```

ERROR

> INFO     2013-10-29 08:27:57,104 module.py:608] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   ERROR    2013-10-29 08:29:43,171 wsgi.py:262] 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/abid/Documents/GAE_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
>       handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
>     File "/home/abid/Documents/GAE_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
>       handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
>     File "/home/abid/Documents/GAE_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
>       obj = **import**(path[0])
>   ImportError: No module named helloworld
>   INFO     2013-10-29 08:29:43,191 module.py:608] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   ERROR    2013-10-29 08:29:51,775 wsgi.py:262] 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/abid/Documents/GAE_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
>       handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
>     File "/home/abid/Documents/GAE_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
>       handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
>     File "/home/abid/Documents/GAE_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
>       obj = **import**(path[0])
>   ImportError: No module named helloworld

1) `ImportError: No module named helloworld` -> i noticed this error

- currently working on this project `exercise1`, copied app.yaml file from previous project `helloworld/`
- checked app.yaml and it's content are as follows:

> application: your-app-id
>   version: 1
>   runtime: python27
>   api_version: 1
>   threadsafe: true
>
> handlers:
>   - url: /.*
>
> > script: helloworld.application>

2) on google [URL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) -> Every request to a URL whose path matches the regular expression /.* (all URLs) should be handled by the application object in the helloworld module.

3) my directory structure

> abid@abid-webdev:~/Documents/GAE_projects$ ls

exercise1
helloworld
google_appengine

Question:

how can i modify my app.yaml to work with my other projects e.g. 
    exercise1?

thanks all for your help.

Comment: Did you manage to run the hello world app from Google? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction you should point to the directory where the app.yaml is and not to the python script when running dev_appserver.py among other things that I can see above

Comment: @Lipis -> yes i can run hello world app, only with default settings [URL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld)

did you mean (point to directory)?? [URL] (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Script_handlers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this from the top!

**For your new project you will need to have this structure in the exercise1 directory:**

```
Directory: exercise1
  File: app.yaml
  File: exercise1.py
```

**In the app.yaml you'll need something like this:**

```
application: your-app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: exercise1.application
```

The line "script: exercise1.application" tells it which file to use (in this case exercise1.py) and the instance of a WSGI Handler to use (in this case application)

**In exercise1.py you'll need something like this:**

```
import webapp2


class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hey Y'all!')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', HomePage),
], debug=True)
```

Here you can see **application** that we referred to in app.yaml.

**Once you have this basic structure you need to start the dev appserver. The way you are doing it in the question is incorrect:**

You need to run the dev_appserver with the directory "exercise1", not a python file.

Assuming that the Google App Engine sdk is still located at "~/Documents/GAE_projects/google_appengine" run the following command from the exercise1 directory:

```
python ~/Documents/GAE_projects/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py ./
```

This will start the dev_appserver.py script telling it to use the current directory (which is what the "./" means).

If you follow this, then you should be up and rolling!

Comment: -> that is actually spot on .. thanks for your input
previous suggestion from [URL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Script_handlers) also were useful. 
how do i mark this solved ?

Comment: Next to my answer should be a grey tick, if you click that it should turn green which will select this as the accepted answer. :)